# How do the Node.js bindings work?

Tags: javascript, c, node.js, architecture

I am trying to sure up my understanding of how exactly Node.js goes from JavaScript to an executed command on a machine. I have seen this workflow diagram:

[image: Node.js workflow]

My understanding is that first javascript get compiled into machine language via the V8 javascript engine. After that I am not exactly sure how the Node.js bindings work. Do they decompile the machine language into C that is entered into the Libuv event loop? Also if a certain line of javascript does not contain a I/O event is it just executed after being compiled by the V8 engine, bypassing the bindings and Libuv?

Comment: What does this have to do with C?

Comment: I don't believe you gonna get an nice answer for this, as from my point of view its way to low level and there are tons of documentation/tutorials/books explaining the internals and creating modules mostly in C++ i don't think anyone uses C to accomplish this anyways.

Comment: @Gntem I don't think I have seen any tutorials/documentation explaining what happens to the javascript in a nodejs application after it has been compiled into machine language by v8 but before it enters the event loop, I have looked for several hours, is there a particular tutorial/documentation you have in mind?

Comment: @NickStaggs https://medium.com/@vardanator/node-js-v8-internals-an-illustrative-primer-83766e983bf6 , https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki , https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples , this is so v8 internals..